# How to count a column's values in database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database similar to this one below and new to SQL programming, how can I count how many "new" and "processing" values inside my status column in SQL query?

```
table name : sample_table
-------------------
id|  name  | status |
-------------------
1.|  Ben   |   new
2.| Alfred |  processing
3.| Jarvis |  new
4.| Leroy  |  processing
5.| Darnel |  processing
```

Comment: That is a 'table'

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: I'm trying to echo  out how many ''new" or "processing" there are on the "status" column in php. for example I want to echo the count of the "processing" values which there are 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum()` to count how many times your condition was true.

In MYSQL you can use:

```
select sum(status = 'processing') as pCount, 
       sum(status = 'new') as nCount
from sample_table
```

or in other DB engines:

```
select sum(case when status = 'processing' then 1 else 0 end) as pCount, 
       sum(case when status = 'new' then 1 else 0 end) as nCount
from sample_table
```

Comment: Might need a trim to cope with the first row which looks like spacenew

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT status, COUNT(status) FROM sample_table GROUP BY status
```